# kendo date dialog on click of input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-datepicker

I have a kendo Date picker it is functioning well.

On click of icon in input box I am able to open date dialog and it is working.
But I want this dialog should also open in click of input box as well..

```
            <h4>Select date:</h4>
            <input kendo-date-picker
             ng-model="dateString"
             k-ng-model="dateObject" />
```

Demo :
http://dojo.telerik.com/

Can anyone guide me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add click listener to datepicker wrapper element an use datepicker open method to open datepicker. Look this [Kendo UI Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/uPEZu)

Comment: Hahaha.. I have done that,, But the thing is I need to close it also right. It should work same as it is working for span icon. calender container should   toggle..

Comment: Well why you not include this requirement to your question?